# ggplot2 - Discrete X Axis Values from Numeric/Integer Data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that I am trying to graph using ggplot2 where the x axis is a numeric/integer value. When graphed, I would like the graph to only show the values of x that are present in the dataset and not add values to the x axis (discrete values). The fully reproducible example below demonstrates the problem: even though the x axis values provided are 1, 3, 25, the resulting graph has 0, 5, 15, 20, 25 rendered on the x axis. I've tried casting the values, as well as trying a discrete scale but none of them seem to have worked.

*Edit* While the values on the x axis are numeric/integer, they represent factors (i.e. number of people in a trial, the number of cylinders in an engine, etc.) and are not continuous values.

```
#Example
library(ggplot2)

row1 <- c(1, 1)
row2 <- c(3, 2)
row3 <- c(25, 10)

data <- data.frame()
data <- rbind(data, row1)
data <- rbind(data, row2)
data <- rbind(data, row3)
names(data) <- c("A", "B")

qplot(A, B, data = data, geom="line")


#Things Tried
qplot(factor(A), B, data = data, geom="line")    #geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
qplot(as.factor(A), B, data = data, geom="line")    #geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
qplot(character(A), B, data = data, geom="line")    #Error in character(A) : invalid 'length' argument
qplot(as.character(A), B, data = data, geom="line")    #geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
qplot(A, B, data = data, geom="line") + scale_x_discrete(breaks = data$A)    #Works, but values are too far apart
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
#START WITH SAMPLE DATA SET AS PER QUESTION
library(ggplot2)
row1 <- c(1, 1)
row2 <- c(3, 2)
row3 <- c(25, 10)

data <- data.frame()
data <- rbind(data, row1)
data <- rbind(data, row2)
data <- rbind(data, row3)
names(data) <- c("A", "B")

#PRODUCE SOLUTION, MODIFY DATASET
df <- data
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
df$Labels <- as.factor(df[,"A"])

#RENDER PLOT
ggplot(df,aes(id,B)) + 
    geom_path() + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$id,labels=df$Labels) +
    labs(x="A")

#EQUIVALENT QPLOT CODE:
qplot(id, B, data = df, geom="line") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$id,labels=df$Labels) + 
    labs(x="A")
```

Which produces the following result:

[image: Result]

For what it is worth, I personally find the above presentation of your data misleading and would be inclined to represent it in the following manner:

```
ggplot(df,aes(id,B)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=Labels),color="black") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$id,labels=paste("Trial:",df$Labels)) +
    labs(x="A",fill="Trial Number",title="Trial XYZ Results") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position=c(0,1),legend.justification=c(0,1))
```

[image: Result2]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution works great, but is it possible for it to be done using the qplot function, rather than ggplot2 function? qplot creates cleaner scripts, so I try to stick with it when I can. Additionally, re: misleading representation: see my edit in my original question.

Comment: @lolcodez Understand, but the numbers imply numeric relationship. I would list them as Trial 1, Trial 2, Trial 25 etc... or something like that. I have added qplot code to my solution.